# ¿Cómo hacer visible un array en toda la clase?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema, me dan una mano por favor. En FOXPRO era muy fácil. En JAVA es algo mas complicado según veo.

En la parte que dice cálculos con los valores del array seleccionado, no logró leer los valores del array seleccionado, el `for` recorre el array pero no lee los valores que debe usar en los cálculos. Por qué?

Gracias

```
public class promedios {

    String control = "H"

    @Override
    public void arreglos() {


        if (control.equals("H")) { 

            double hombres[][] = {{0, 1.80, 90, 2},
                            {1, 1.75, 74, 4},
                            {2, 1.84, 79, 3},
                            {3, 1.85, 94, 1},
                           .......
                            {99, 1.75, 74, 3}};
   
            control = "M"

        }else{

            double mujeres[][] = {{0, 1.75, 60, 2},
                            {1, 1.73, 71, 4},
                            {2, 1.80, 74, 2},
                            {3, 1.68, 74, 4},
                          ....... 
                            {99, 1.75, 67, 1}};
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) {

            // calculos con los valores del array seleccionado
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En el libro *Introducción a la Programación con Java* de *Jhon y Raymond Dean* explican muy bien tu problema.
Por ejemplo este arreglo.

```
int[][] x = new int[2][3];
for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) //Aquí se comprueba la variable i < 2
{
    for (int j=0; j<x[0].length; j++) //Aquí se comprueba la variable j < 3
    {
        
    } // end for j
} // end for i
```

> Puesto que en realidad x es una referencia a un arreglo de 2 elementos, x.length contiene el valor 2. Como puede verse antes, x[0] es una referencia a un arreglo de 3 elementos. Por tanto, x[0].length contiene el valor 3. Lo importante de todo esto es que la propiedad length puede usarse para iterar a través de los elementos en un arreglo de dos dimensiones.

Por tanto compañero. Si quieres por ejemplo calcular el promedio completo de los hombres podría ser de esta forma

```
double suma = 0;
int indices = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < hombres.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < hombres[i].length; j++){
        suma += hombres[i][j];
        indices++;
    }   
}
double promedio = suma / indices;
```

Para utilizar los arreglos `hombres` y `muejeres` debes declararlos al principio del método `arreglos()` porque están declarados dentro de las condiciones, lo cual los hace una variable local que sólo funciona dentro de dichas condiciones, una vez que terminan de ejecutarse la JVM las elimina. Quedaría asi:

```
public void arreglos (){
    double [][] arreglo;
    ...
    if (control.equals("H")) { 

        arreglo = {{0, 1.80, 90, 2},
                        {1, 1.75, 74, 4},
                        {2, 1.84, 79, 3},
                        {3, 1.85, 94, 1},
                       .......
                        {99, 1.75, 74, 3}};

        control = "M"

    }else{

        arreglo = {{0, 1.75, 60, 2},
                        {1, 1.73, 71, 4},
                        {2, 1.80, 74, 2},
                        {3, 1.68, 74, 4},
                      ....... 
                        {99, 1.75, 67, 1}};
    }
double suma = 0;
int indices = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < arreglo[i].length; j++){
        suma += arreglo[i][j];
        indices++;
    }   
}
double promedio = suma / indices;
System.out.println ("El promedio es" +promedio);
}
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y que hayas entendido. Un saludo compañera

Comment: Compañero gracias por responder, tengo claro lo que me explicas, el for recorre el array sin problemas, lo se, porque con un Toast lo chequeo. Lo que me sucede, es que los valores que toma del array para hacer los cálculos están en  en cero (0) siempre, es como si el array selecciondo no fuera visible a la hora de hacer los cálculos.

Comment: Entiendo @Isabel, Parece ser que el problema esta a la hora de declarar los arreglos. Están declarados dentro del bloque de tus condiciones if. Lo que debes hacer es declarar esos arreglos al comienzo del método arreglos (). Edité mi respuesta para corregir el problema.

Comment: Gracias Ariel Eliezer hice lo que tu me sugeriste, declarar los arrays fuera del if, al principio del método, pero me genera error, solo me funciona cuando declaro, creo e inicializo los arrays fuera del condicionante, al inicio del método, Lo que buscaba con el condicionante era no sobre cargar la memoria con todos los arrays, unicamente cargar el array que necesitaba para los cálculos. Alguna sugerencia.

Comment: Entiendo @isabel. Entonces puedes declarar un sólo array al inicio del método `arreglos ()`, luego inicializas ese array en el `if` y obtienes los valores de ese único array para calcular el promedio. De esa forma sólo tendrás un solo arreglo en lugar de dos. Edité mi respuesta pata adaptarla a lo que quieres

Comment: Ariel Eliezer gracias, hice tal cual lo que tu me sugeriste, declare un solo array afuera del `if` y lo inicialice dentro del `if`,pero me sigue generando un error al compilar  **la variable arreglo no a sido declarada**  incluso tuve que usar la sentencia  **arreglo = new double [][] {}**  y aun así me genera el mismo error al compilar. Lo he revisado n veces y esta tal cual tu me dijiste, que podrá ser?

Comment: @idabel podrías añadir el código que tienes hasta ahora en tu pregunta, para ver si podemos encontrar lo que está mal